# Forbidden with Spring Security and @Secured

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have setup Spring Security as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private MongoUserDetailsService userServiceDetails;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptEncoder;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index", true)
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
       .userDetailsService(userServiceDetails)
       .passwordEncoder(bCryptEncoder);
}
```

And on my controller I have the following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Secured({"ADMIN"})
public List<Item> getItems(@RequestBody filter filter) {

    if (filter.hasMissingField()) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    return service.getItems(filter);
}
```

On logging in the user details object has the roles needed (In debug):

[image]

However, I am getting a 403 - Forbidden. I can't see why. If I remove the @Secured then I can access the page fine, but with @Secured({"ADMIN"}) it fails.

I have combed SO and I see errors in relation to [@Secured not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275890/can-not-get-the-secured-method-security-annotations-working-in-spring-security), errors in relation to [@Secured having no effects at the Controller level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674739/global-method-security-in-spring-boot) but not like my current scenario where it is failing to authorise with the needed role present.

If it helps I am using Spring Boot 1.3.2.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you need to say `@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})` instead?

Comment: Thanks @gerrytan that worked. I didn't know one had to prefix roles. Thanks you saved me a bunch ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to put `@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})` with `ROLE_` prefix

Comment: Thanks.. Can't up vote you due to reputation but your comments definitely solved the problem. Thanks.